# webpack - how to require a dynamic/runtime module

Tags: dynamic, module, webpack

We're migrating from Require JS to webpack. In our project, we were able to require a runtime-based url as a module (to our SignalR proxies - these are generated at runtime) and that file was downloaded completely before the module requiring that fired off. I haven't-yet determined how to achieve the same effect using webpack except for an unsavory syncrhonous xhr request to get the script, which is a deprecated approach. What am I missing?

So the desired effect is to be able to have the top-most consumer require a module which internally requires the core SignalR lib (which we get like normal) and *then* this runtime-based (that url) script as a module, before running the top-most consumer's code.